# Random point in a d-dimensional ball

Tags: randomized-algorithms

I would like to know if there any algorithm to pick a random grid point inside a d-dimensional ball with a given radius R.  And if there any algorithm to pick a random arbitrary point inside a d-dimensional ball with a given radius R.

Thanks.

Comment: I was also interested in such an algorithm, and I would be pleased if someone could provide at least something close to pseudo code. Browsed almost whole stack overflow and couldn't find anything getting me closer to the answer.

Comment: http://blog.geomblog.org/2013/01/a-sampling-gem-sampling-from-ellp-balls.html

Comment: The posted answer works well for $R > d^{3/2}$. for smaller $R$, you might want to use the Metropolis algorithm — that should be much more efficient in this case.

Answer (score 5):

For the latter, [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136314/what-is-a-good-method-to-find-random-points-on-the-n-sphere-when-n-is-large/136333#136333) is a good starting point.  For the former, I guess finding a random point in the ball, rounding it to a grid point, then checking that grid point is in the ball.

Comment: Your algorithm for the first problem will give a nonuniform distribution, as points near the boundary may have lower probability. You may fix it by starting with a random point in a ball with radius $R+1$ rather than $1$. Either way, this will have good probability of success only if $R=\Omega(d)$ or so.

Comment: I meant, rather than $R$, of course.

Comment: True, I suppose you could use $R + (n\delta)^{1/n}$ as your sampling ball radius, i.e., add a grid-cell diagonal width ...

Comment: You are right, it should be the diagonal width. That is $\sqrt{d}$ (though actually half of it is enough). What is $n$ and $\delta$?

Comment: $\delta$ the grid separation, $n$ the dimension (I see I should have used $d$ for that)

Comment: Of course that should be $R+(d \delta)^{1/2}$ ....

Comment: I see. Since the OP didn’t mention it, I assumed the grid has unit separation, but this doesn’t really matter as everything scales linearly with $\delta$. So, the radius needs to be $R+\frac\delta2\sqrt d$. The expected number of trials is exponential in $\approx d^{3/2}\delta/R$, hence it works well for $R/\delta=\Omega(d^{3/2})$.

Comment: @jjg. Thank you so much for your comments. I know that we can sample a random point in a bigger ball B'. But I have no ideas about how much larger of the ball B'. Could you please give some hints? Thanks.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek. Thank you so much for your comments. Could you please explain more detail about squrt (d)/2  is enough? Thanks.

Comment: @PengfeiGu The rejection-sampling-with-rounding algorithm works correctly if the sampled body (here, the larger ball) includes all points $x$ whose nearest grid-point $x'$ is in the target ball of radius $R$. Now, $x-x'$ is a vector whose all coordinates are at most $1/2$ in absolute value (assuming unit grid), hence of Euclidean norm at most $\frac12\sqrt d$. Thus, all such $x$ are included in the ball with radius $R+\frac12\sqrt d$ by the triangle inequality.

Answer (score -9):

In view of a circle with center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$, the points $(x,y)$ on the circle fulfill
$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$.
In parametric form, the points are given by $x=a+r\cos\phi$ and $y=b+r\sin\phi$ with angle $\phi$ between 0 and $2\pi$.

Thus finding a random point in the circle is to choose an angle $\phi$ uniformly at random and a number $d$ with $0\leq d\leq r$ uniformly at random.

Comment: This will not give uniform distribution on the disk. You need larger $d$ to have larger probability.

Comment: Indeed, I knew it but have no solution here.

Comment: Why would you post something you know to be wrong? Not to mention it's an easy special case of the other answer.

Comment: Easy approximation.